# Quota calculator for YouTube Stream API

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

I am trying to find the quota for broadcast insert and bind. I can not find anything in the YouTube Data API quota calculator. Do you know the quota for this?

Also, is `video.insert` performed when a `LiveBroadcasts.insert` is performed?

Thank you for your help.